# Activity did appear

Tags: android, android-activity, viewflipper, oncreate

I have a 3 Activities, and all of them has a a ViewFlipper with some images that keep running. The thing is that I load these images from the SDCard, and there are aproximatly 180 images.

EVERY TIME I call one of these activities, it takes some time to the ViewFlipper be completed.. I would like to know if there is something like onAppear for Android..
The contents of Activity changes everytime it gets called, so it can't be singleTask..

I would like to know if there is a way to refresh an Activity content, but without loosing its contents.. Like this: on the onCreate, everything would be done normal, but on something like onAppear, I would only change what I need, so that onCreate would be called only once.

This is how I change between the three Activities:

```
startActivity(new Intent(FirstOne.this, OtherOne.class));
```

Comment: Please do your homework first: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

Answer (score 8):

You probably need to override the [onResume()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onResume%28%29) method

Comment: Yup this is great!

Answer (score 0):

If you separate the loading of your images from the Activity by writing an in-memory cache, you can optimize the load times for images that will be used more than once.